# Как лучше сделать хранилище данных мониторинга php mysql sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

Есть у меня задумка сделать для личного пользования систему, которая получает данные с интервалом, ну скажем 5 минут, и записывает всё это в какую-то БД. На публичной части будет пару `datepiker-ов`, по которым будет фильтроваться выдача всех собранных данных за период и из полученных данных будут формироваться графики. Это практически весь функционал, вопрос в реализации только один, где и в каком виде хранить эти данные? Данных будет много, но каждая строка будет содержать только дату запроса и 4-5 цифровых значений длинной 2-3 символа.
При вводе каждые 5 минут это 288 записей в сутки, примерно 8640 в месяц, 103680 в год. Хотелось бы иметь возможность смотреть далеко в прошлое, по этому регулярную очистку данных не хочется делать.

Так вот вопрос, в каком виде хранить эти данные более разумно? `Mysql, sqlite`, может еще что-то? Фильтрация по дате, сортировки, всё это тоже должно быть.

Comment: 100к записей в год по 30 символов штука - это вообще ниачём. Любая БД. С учётом того, что планируется самописка... если на PHP - то MySQL, если на некоем ЯП - то любая embedded, которая отлизана для этого языка.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://clickhouse.yandex/ она как раз предназначена для работы с большими данными

Comment: Планирую использовать php